# Report Viewer error: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, report-viewer2010, ssrs-2012

We have a web applicaiton which displays the SSRS reports in a Report Viewer. 
All was working fine from last 10 months. But suddenly from last three days users are getting below error while viewing the reports:

```
    System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetConnectionSSLForMethod(String methodname)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetParameters()
   at ViewReport.showReport(Guid ReportID, String ReportName, String ReportPath, Boolean isExport, Boolean isHeirarchy, String UserName, Decimal repID)
```

Not every user is facing this error. I also tried to test the reports and I was shocked to see that sometimes this error comes and sometimes not for the same report. 
I am using the Report Viewer 10 in my application and passing the SSRS Admin credentials for pulling the report.

I have `httpruntime executiontimeout` set to 20 minutes in my application.  Can this be a culprit of this error as this error is coming after two days when I changed this property from default to 20 minutes to increase the Report Timeout.

Please help me guys as this error is killing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem by moving my code from Page_load event to Page_Init event.